# WebView handle redirect click link with Intent.ACTION_VIEW

Tags: android, webview, hyperlink, click, android-webview

I've a difficult managing open link on `webview` content click with `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` on different device.

My scenario is: i've some html code displayed within a `webview` inside my app, this content have some link (href), then on click event i want to open the link with external app and not inside the same web view.

I've achieved this by:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(request.getUrl().toString()));
        activity.startActivity(intent);    
        return true;
    }
});
```

So, the problem is that this doesn't happen an all devices.

With Android 7 it's working but on version 6 doesn't. Anyway to manage different version i've already used different implementation.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        activity.startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
});
```

I've already look around on stackoverflow but the only answer i've found it's to use the code above.

Thanks for the support

**UPDATE - 15/02/18**
I've solved the problem, putting the two `@Override` method together like this:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(request.getUrl().toString()));
        activity.startActivity(intent);    
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        activity.startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because the method you are using was added only in API 24 (7.0), so it doesn't exist on older APIs, check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)). What you need to do is to use the [old one](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)) in this case. It is declared as `Deprecated`, but you still can use it.

Comment: Thank for the answer @nikis, i've already check the version using this `if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)` then if it's true i'll use the first block code on the question, else the second one; but the "issue" still remain