# Can I call super within a Listener Lambda in Android-Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda, android-webview

I am trying to override the download Listener for a WebView so it gets to open websites not belonging to us in an external browser instead of loading them in the webview. Thing is, I'd like to simplify the code into something like this

```
webView?.setDownloadListener { url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimetype, contentLength ->
        if (!url.contains("mydomain")) {
            CLog.v("InternalWebviewFragment.configWebView().setDownloadListener() isNOTmydomain url: $url")
            val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            activity?.startActivity(i)

        }else{
            super(url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimetype, contentLength)
        }
    }
```

However, that call to super there, which I intend to have for urls that do belong to our domain, says that can only be used on the left hand of a dot. When I try to type

```
super.onDownloadStart
```

it gives an `unresolved reference error`.

How could I get the webview Listener to go on business as usual when the url is part of our domain? Is the super call only available in non-lambda methods?

Comment: "...open websites not belonging to us in an external browser instead of loading them in the webview..." Why not just use `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` ?

Comment: I thought so, but API 21 (our app supports 21-29) goes through onDownload instead :\

Comment: why do you need that, `onDownloadStart` has no default implementation

Comment: But `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is also available for lower APIs, isn't it?

Comment: @Demigod it is available, but when I follow the Logcat, it never goes through ```shouldOverrideUrlLoading ```

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon well, I guess that's why there's no super.

Comment: @FranciscoGarcía, I still think, this is the right approach to do this (using `shouldOverrideUrlLoading `) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/36484720/3569545

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself correctly. If so, I'm sorry. We do have a ```shouldOverrideUrlLoading``` method dealing with this. Checking the LogCat I see that API 29 does take that route, but API 21, by some reason, doesn't. API 21 goes to ```onDownloadStart```. And if I take out the piece of code I pasted on the question (while keeping the ```shouldOverrideUrlLoading```, of course) it just won't do a thing in API 21, you click on an external link and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

After many tests, @Demigod's approach turned out to be the right one. It just needed the bit of having both deprecated and current methods of shouldOverrideUrlLoading as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48662290/webview-handle-redirect-click-link-with-intent-action-view)

```
        // APIs up to 23 need this method
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
            if (!url.contains("mydomain")) {
                // InternalWebviewFragment external (non mydomain) urls will be dispatched to an external browser
                CLog.v("InternalWebviewFragment.getSimpleWebViewClientUrlLoading().shouldOverrideUrlLoadingOLD() isNotmydomain url: $url")
                val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
                activity?.startActivity(i)
                CLog.v("InternalWebviewFragment.getSimpleWebViewClientUrlLoading().shouldOverrideUrlLoadingOLD() isNotmydomain  After Intent")
                return true //InternalWebviewFragment this avoids the webview to load the url we've just sent to the browser
            }
            CLog.v("InternalWebviewFragment.getSimpleWebViewClientUrlLoading().shouldOverrideUrlLoadingOLD() ismydomain url: $url")
            // mydomain urls should load fine in the webview
            view?.loadUrl(url)
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url)

        }
        // for APIs 24+
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
            view: WebView?,
            request: WebResourceRequest?
        ): Boolean {
            if (!request?.url.toString().contains("mydomain")) {
                // InternalWebviewFragment external (non mydomain) urls will be dispatched to an external browser
                CLog.v("InternalWebviewFragment.getSimpleWebViewClientUrlLoading().shouldOverrideUrlLoading2() isNotmydomain url: ${request?.url.toString()}")
                val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(request?.url.toString()))
                activity?.startActivity(i)
                CLog.v("InternalWebviewFragment.getSimpleWebViewClientUrlLoading().shouldOverrideUrlLoading2() isNotmydomain After Intent")
                return true //InternalWebviewFragment this avoids the webview to load the url we've just sent to the browser
            }
            CLog.v("InternalWebviewFragment.getSimpleWebViewClientUrlLoading().shouldOverrideUrlLoading() ismydomain url: $url")
            // mydomain urls should load fine in the webview
            view?.loadUrl(request?.url.toString())
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request)
        }
```